# Dirichlet series, analytic continuation and convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, analyticity, dirichlet-series

Suppose we have a Dirichlet series, and we know that it has an analytic continuation f(s), which has no poles in the region $Re(s) > \sigma$.

Can we say anything about the abscissa of convergence of the series?

(Obvious example: $(1 - 2^{1-s}) \zeta(s) = \sum_n (-1)^n n^{-s}$; the left-hand side is entire, but the right-hand side has abscissa of convergence 0.)

Comment: As you see, no ${}{}{}$. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(n) n^{-s}$ and other Dirichlet series or Mellin transforms coming from $\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$ are a very special case, having poles on its abscissa of convergence (or arbitrary close to it). If you want a general analytic continuation, you can look at $f(x) = x^m\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n e^{-nx}$. If $F(s)$ is analytic then $ \int_0^\infty (f(x)-\sum_{k=0}^K \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} x^k 1_{x < 1}) x^{s-1}dx= F(s+m)\Gamma(s+m)-\sum_{k=0}^K \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} \frac{1}{s+k-1}$ is analytic for $\Re(s) > -K$

Comment: This is similar to what I'm hoping for: I'd like e.g. two kernels $K_c(s)$ and $K_d(s)$ such that if $\int_{\sigma - i\infty}^{\sigma + i\infty} K_{c,d}(s+s') f(s') ds'$ converges/diverges, then the associated Dirichlet series converges/diverges at $s$.

Comment: There is no such. You can only look at $\lim_{x \to \infty} \int_{\sigma - i\infty}^{\sigma + i\infty} f(s+w) x^s \frac{ds}{s}$ where $x^s$ doesn't converge in the sense of distributions (well it converges to $\delta(s-w)$ which is an analytic functional)

Comment: There are no such kernels -- is this known as a fact, or is it that there are no such kernels known?

Comment: There is no simple criterion to check if it converges at a point. Do you know that if $F(w) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-w}$ converges then $\frac{F(s+w)}{s} = \int_1^\infty (\sum_{n \le x} a_n n^{-w}) x^{-s-1}dx$ is uniformly bounded and $L^2$ for $\Re(s) \ge \epsilon > 0$ ?

Comment: Can you give me a source for that?  It sounds like it would be helpful.

Comment: What did you try ? It is not hard..